# Greek letter encoding issue

Tags: x-cart

I am using x-cart version is 4.2.3.

I have Greek letter conversion issue in a functionality . i.e Greek character  αβΓ is converting to  Î±Î²Î“. Is there any way to avoid these encoding.It is not a browser encoding issue , server is converting these Greek letter to these characters. Please let me know if there is any solution to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of the database supporting utf8 encoding.

You could try the steps referred in [here](http://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart%3aFAQs#How_do_I_set_up_my_X-Cart_to_support_UTF-8.3F) (question: "How do I set up my X-Cart to support UTF-8?")